# Elasticsearch NEST client compatibility

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, nest

According to the NEST matrix compatibility https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/readme.md#compatibility-matrix, i'm having some troubles!, we worked for a long time with NEST 2.5 client & Elasticsearch 5.4 server without any problem, and now with an in-local test (NEST alway 2.5 version with Elasticsearch 7.5) seems works fine (index creation, indexing, searching ...).

can you please help me to understand ?

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility matrix lists the *supported* compatible versions. It may well be the case that for the APIs you use that you find that 2.5 works with 7.5, but this is coincidental and not something supported or tested to be compatible. In addition, if you do come across an issue, the first suggestion will be to change to a compatible version.